# How security in ASPNET Web Pages, really works?

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-webpages

I want to understand, **how can I secure a WebSite made with ASP.NET Web Pages at the very basic level?**. The problem is that I always find the same explanation about using the builtin provider that creates a series of tables and use a predefined model. I don't want to use that immediatelly, I want to start from zero, and I mean real zero, passing by:

- Securing by a variable content    ....I know is ridiculuous but I want to get in real simple terms how security works.
- Securing by data that already exists ....My model, not a predefined one.

I found the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks310b8y(v=vs.100).aspx that explain how "ASP.NET Security" works but when I start the reading I get confuse by the different frameworks that conforms ASP.NET.
Could this content be applied to "ASP.NET Web Pages" or they applied only to Web Forms? Is Web Pages completelly diferent?

Following the advice of Joe, I clarify that when I refer to "Secure a Website" I mean **give access to specific parts of a site only to specific users**.

Comment: are you asking about authentication and sessions?  you might want to specify your question a little before people vote you down and close you.

Comment: thanks @JoeCoderGuy, I add a paragraph trying to be more clear.

Comment: @DennisTraub I put it in bold in a try to clarify..Maybe I need to edit the title mmmm

Comment: Check [Form and Role based Authentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36836/Forms-Authentication-and-Role-based-Authorization)